# TCP ECN source code

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

I had problem understanding Linux Source Code of TCP (net/ipv4/tcp_input.c)
in include/net/tcp.h it already defined TCP_ECN_OK = 1 but what really means

```
tp->ecn_flags & TCP_ECN_OK
```

Besides, please explain between socket, sock, tcp_sock, sk_buff.

Is there any references that explain more detailed or make it clearer.

Thank you.

**Update:**

The networking part of the kernel uses mainly two data structures: one to keep the state of a connection called **sock** (for "socket"), and another to keep the data and the status of both incoming and outgoing packets called **sk_buff** (for "socket buﬀer"). Both of them are described in this section. We also include a brief description of tcp_opt, a structure that is part of the sock structure and is used to maintain the TCP connection state. 
(*from "A Map of the Networking Code in Linux Kernel 2.4.20"*)

Comment: For "*please explain between socket, sock, tcp_sock, sk_buff.*" part of question - this is too broad to be explained in single answer. Please, do read some books/articles about linux network subsystem (e.g. http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/group) , and ask something more specific, than "between Sun Earth and Jupiter".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TCP_ECN_OK` is bit flag from linuxkernel's internal [`struct tcp_sock` as](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/tcp.h?v=3.14#L214) (field `ecn_flags`). There are several bitflags in it ([`include/net/tcp.h` file](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/net/tcp.h?v=3.14#L398) from linux kernel sources):

```
398 #define TCP_ECN_OK              1
399 #define TCP_ECN_QUEUE_CWR       2
400 #define TCP_ECN_DEMAND_CWR      4
401 #define TCP_ECN_SEEN            8
```

Expression `tp->ecn_flags & TCP_ECN_OK` is the logic test, is the TCP_ECN_OK still set or not.

Update: I think that `TCP_ECN_OK` bit is set when the tcp socket is open (if the current settings of sysctl enables ECN support in Linux), and it will stay set if the other side of socket supports ECN too.

As said in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explicit_Congestion_Notification

> ECN is an optional feature that is only used when both endpoints support it and are willing to use it.
>
> ... skip to Linux section
>
> The Linux kernel supports three working modes of the ECN for TCP, as configured by value of the /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_ecn variable, through the sysctl interface:[11 - [tcp_ecn  in `Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt)]
>
> - 0 – disable ECN and neither initiate nor accept it
> - 1 – enable ECN when requested by incoming connections, and also request ECN on outgoing connection attempts
> - 2 – enable ECN when requested by incoming connections, but do not request ECN on outgoing connections. // DEFAULT in 3.14 //
>
> The default value is 2, meaning that by default ECN is enabled when requested by incoming connections, but it is not requested on outgoing connections. Anyway, ECN is used by the Linux kernel only when both ends of the TCP connection indicate support for it.[11]

For example, when we send SYN in beginning of outgoing socket connection, and sysctl `tcp_ecn` is enabled for outgoing connections ("sysctl_tcp_ecn" flag is `1`), we set ECE bit in tcp header and set TCP_ECN_OK. [net/ipv4/tcp_output.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c?v=3.14#L311) Line 315

```
315 /* Packet ECN state for a SYN.  */
316 static inline void TCP_ECN_send_syn(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)
....
320         tp->ecn_flags = 0;
321         if (sock_net(sk)->ipv4.sysctl_tcp_ecn == 1) {
322                 TCP_SKB_CB(skb)->tcp_flags |= TCPHDR_ECE | TCPHDR_CWR;
323                 tp->ecn_flags = TCP_ECN_OK;
324         }
```

Later, if the other side of connection have no support of ECN or it is disabled, we will unset TCP_ECN_OK flag.
[net/ipv4/tcp_input.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_input.c?v=3.14#L246) Line 246

```
246 static inline void TCP_ECN_rcv_synack(struct tcp_sock *tp, const struct tcphdr *th)
247 {
248         if ((tp->ecn_flags & TCP_ECN_OK) && (!th->ece || th->cwr))
249                 tp->ecn_flags &= ~TCP_ECN_OK;
250 }
```

For incoming connections, we unset TCP_ECN_OK, if in incoming SYN there was no ECE tcp header flag (read more about flags and ECN in [RFC3168 "*The Addition of Explicit Congestion Notification (ECN) to IP*"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3168))

```
252 static inline void TCP_ECN_rcv_syn(struct tcp_sock *tp, const struct tcphdr *th)
253 {
254         if ((tp->ecn_flags & TCP_ECN_OK) && (!th->ece || !th->cwr))
255                 tp->ecn_flags &= ~TCP_ECN_OK;
256 }
```

Comment: Thank you osgx, of course I understand the operators, what I doubt is its meaning. Maybe TCP_ECN_OK presents a state that says ECN is enabled.

Comment: Sorry, thank you for information. I'll try to find meaning by searching usage of this bit http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=TCP_ECN_OK

Comment: you're such a genius. Thanks a million. Do you major in this thing - ECN, TCP Congestion Control?

Comment: I'm watching at ECN docs only for 2 hours. Just bit of googling (tcp ecn linux)

Answer (score 0):

A good reference for explaining in details Linux Networking Source Code can be found here at [A Map of the Networking Code in Linux Kernel 2.4.20](http://mgoutell.free.fr/fichiers/KernMap.pdf)

Comment: ECN logic is on pages 24-25, section "6.5 ECN". But there is no exact information on `TCP_ECN_OK` bit, only overview of ECN logic.